Is there any way to get VBA to get the current user's Full Name from a Windows user account without using CMD?
Is there any way to get VBA to get the current user's Full Name from a Windows user account without using CMD?
I have a team who all work collaboratively on Excel files on Windows machines. We are on a domain but cannot use OneDrive to work collaboratively.
To help keep track of edits I have written some VBA to record a timestamp and current user on each save (below).
Environ("Username") returns their Windows Username, which is something like ID1234. I know that all users are configured to have a Full Name like (Company) Flash Steel associated with their user account.
The Full Name is much more useful for record keeping.
I have used a previous answer calling 'net user' in CMD.exe and parsing the SDTOUT. This works but I was hoping for something more elegant and hopefully called natively in VBA.
' When saving, append the user ID and timestamp
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ...
    Worksheets("Front Cover").Range(nextTimestampCell).Value = Format(Now(), "yy/mm/dd - HH:nn:ss")
    ' Build string for command
    cMDcommand = "cmd /c net user """ & Environ("Username") & """ /DOMAIN | find /I ""Full name"""
    ' Execute command and read top line
    result = Trim(CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec(cMDcommand).StdOut.readline)
    ' Trim result and output User
    Worksheets("Front Cover").Range(nextUserCell).Value = Right(result, Len(result) - 29)
End Sub


What does Application.UserName return? (Might not be what you're looking for tho).

Application.UserName worked like a charm! If you suggest "Worksheets("Front Cover").Range(nextUserCell).Value = Application.UserName" as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

@BigBen - have you seen the message from the OP

You could also use ENVIRON("Username")

@jkpieterse - the OP explicitly said in their post "Environ("Username") returns their Windows Username, which is something like ID1234"

My bad, apologies!

Since you're working in Excel, perhaps use Application.UserName:
Worksheets("Front Cover").Range(nextUserCell).Value = Application.UserName


'Application.UserName' can be overwritten by anybody since it's writable. The value is stored in the registry by "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-xx-...\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo".

@rotabor thanks, that is good to know. This isn't an issue for my needs but important to note for something more serious recording users by full user name.

This doesn't apply in your case, just adding for completeness. If your User Name is set up differently in Excel than the Network (it happens, plus Office can be personalised) and you absolutely need the name as held on the Domain, then this function will work
Function GetUserFullName() As String
' use the Active Directory user object to get user name
    Dim objNetwork As Object
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    With objNetwork
        GetUserFullName = GetObject("WinNT://" & .UserDomain & "/" & .UserName & ",user").FullName
    End With
End Function


GetObject("WinNT://" & .UserDomain & "/" & .UserName & ",user").FullName may not work. Use .UserDomain & "/" & .UserName

True. It does very much depend on how the domains are configured. Unfortunately .UserDomain & "/" & .UserName will return the logon id rather than the full name, so  may as well just use Environ("Username")

This answer also worked for me.
